# How to Record an RTMP Stream?

Tags: c#, record, rtmp

I need to record an RTMP stream (video) from a remote server.
I know the FluorineFX solution but it includes a flash slave that does publish to local host.
Because the DLL will run on a production server I need this solution to be Pure c#

Do you know how can I do it?
I don't actually need code samples I just need a pointer to an open source solution that I can reconfigure, refactor and publish.

again, the solution needs to be pure c# with no extra Flash or anything else.
preferably open source but a symbolic fee is also OK.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? I am trying to accomplish the same thing.ie.
1. Publish video from webcam to Media Server such as Red5
2. Retrieve published video in another application from Red5.
If you have found a solution, please do share. Thanks

Comment: @SteveJohnson, I could not find a decent solution for that.

This is from a long time ago, I can't even remember what came out of the project/task. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this library and looks as if they have the details covered.
http://www.broccoliproducts.com/softnotebook/rtmpclient/rtmpclient.php

Comment: rtmpclient library from borrocoli doesnt seem to have an option of publishing the stream.